# java.io.IOException weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I had this issue with a deploy of a spring boot application on weblogic 12c server. The problem is that when I try to deploy this application on my local weblogic server it works fine, but when I deploy the same application (EAR) on pre-prod server, it doesn't.

The weblogic error is: `java.io.IOException weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException`

Comment: What's the Spring Boot version?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0, jdk 1.8

Comment: Does your servlet initializer implement `WebApplicationInitializer` as per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-weblogic)?

Comment: no, my servlet inizializer extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version of weblogic server(12.1.3), it doesn't support spring boot 2.2.4. For fix this issue the solution was downgrade my spring boot application to 2.0.4 version.

Comment: how did you find this? where can I find a compatibility matrix?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was different. I had below dependency in pom.xml and it was making this issue on WebLogic: 12.1.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Changed it like below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then issue is resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).